# Optimal path through a DAG with sparsely available edge weights

Tags: shortest-path

I would like to create a plot of certain metrics that are collected at revisions of a software system.  The objective of the software engineers is to minimize those metrics.

For version control, the engineers are using Git, so there is a DAG of commits (revisions).  However, the metrics are only available for a *subset* of those commits.  It is not feasible to collect metrics for all of the commits.

What path finding algorithm would yield the most relevant data to plot a "downward trend" in the metrics that is **minimally erratic**, resolving **ties** in favor of the path with **maximum detail**?

## Definitions

**erraticism**: The sum of the absolute differences between the metric at each pair of adjacent commits along the path.  Example: For path `A-B-C` where `A=10`, `B=7`, `C=5`, the erraticism is `(10 - 7) + (7 - 5) = 3 + 2 = 5`.

**detail**: The quantity of commits that have known metrics along a path.  Example: for path `D-E-F` where the metric at `D` and `F` is known, but `E` is unknown, the detail is `2`.

## Scenarios to illustrate objective function

### Metrics available for all paths

Say that `D` is the most recent commit. `D` has two parents, `B` and `C`.  `B` and `C` share a single parent `A`.

```
  10 -> A
       / \
11 -> B   C <- 7
       \ /
   5 -> D
```

In this scenario, all four commits have metrics available. In this case, the least "erratic" path is preferred.

If `A=10`, `B=11`, `C=7`, and `D=5`, the path `A-C-D` is preferred.

### Metrics available for only one competing path

If the metric is unavailable for commit `C`, then the path `A-B-D` is preferred.

```
  10 -> A
       / \
11 -> B   C <- unknown
       \ /
   5 -> D
```

### Metrics available for no competing paths

If the metrics are only known for commits `A` and `D`, then it doesn't matter whether we traverse through commit `B` or commit `C`, because neither commit will be displayed on the plot.  The plot will display path `A-D`.

```
       10 -> A
            / \
unknown -> B   C <- unknown
            \ /
        5 -> D
```

### Competing paths of various lengths

#### Maximum detail

This is where it gets complicated.

Generally it is preferable to have more detail in the plot.  So in the following example, path `A-C-E-F` is preferred:

```
       10 -> A
            / \
      7 -> B   C <- 8
           |   |
unknown -> D   E <- 6
            \ /
        5 -> F
```

Path `A-B-D-F` has `erraticism=5`, `detail=3`.  Path `A-C-E-F` has `erraticism=5`, `detail=4`.  Detail breaks the tie, and path `A-C-E-F` is selected.

#### Minimally erratic

However, we do not prefer the path with greater detail when that path is more erratic than the alternative.  In this case, path `A-B-F` is preferred:

```
       10 -> A
            / \
      7 -> B   C <- 11
           |   |
unknown -> D   E <- 6
            \ /
        5 -> F
```

Path `A-B-D-F` has `erraticism=5`, `detail=3`.  Path `A-C-E-F` has `erraticism=7`, `detail=4`. Path `A-B-D-F` is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the edits.  However, your question is no longer internally self-consistent.  For your example "Metrics available for only one competing path", the path A-C-D has minimal erraticism; there are no ties, so the detail doesn't come into it.  Perhaps you need to clarify/revise your definition of the erraticism of a path where metrics are not available for some nodes along the path?

Comment: Is it possible to formulate your problem as a pure graph theory problem? I see the terminology used so difficult to understand.

Comment: @D.W. I think the challenging part about this problem is deciding which optimality criteria results in a plot that is most useful (and to some extent, aesthetically pleasing) to readers. To restore consistency, I'd like to say that if there is at least one path with `detail > 0`, then all of the remaining paths with `detail=0` should be stricken from consideration.  I'm not sure how best to articulate that in graph-theoretic terms.

Comment: 1. That *is* in graph-theoretic terms.  Don't worry about the terms; give us a precise, unambiguous, internally-consistent specification, and we can handle the rest.  2. Your proposed change doesn't help: your proposed criterion will still select A-C-D for "Metrics available for only one competing path", whereas the question says you want A-B-D. 3. I recommend you spend some time listing some examples, identifying which path you would want, and then try to find an objective function that is consistent with all of those.  (...)

Comment: (...) You need to give us a self-consistent well-defined problem statement before we can do anything with this.  If you want to get a useful answer, the first step is to make sure you are asking a meaningful question: you have to be able to articulate which answer you want, before we can possibly come up with an algorithm that computes that one.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not self-consistent, so you first need to figure out exactly what you are looking for, before we can identify an algorithm to find it.

However, once you figure that out, it is likely that dynamic programming will solve your problem.  Dynamic programming is powerful and likely to solve your problem for any reasonable criterion that depends only on detail and erraticism (assuming it is monotonic in each variable separately).

In particular, define $f(v,d)$ as follows:

> $f(v,d) = $ the smallest possible erraticism that can be achieved by a path from $A$ to $v$ whose detail is $d$.

In other words,

$$f(v,d) = \min \{\text{erraticism}(p) : p \text{ is a path from $A$ to $v$ and } \text{detail}(p)=d\}.$$

Let $\text{pred}(v)$ denote the set of vertices $u$ such that there is a path from $u$ to $v$ where you have the metric for $u$ but not for any other intermediate vertex in the path (i.e., not for any other vertex in the path other than $u$ or $v$).

Notice you can compute $f(v,d)$ given the values of $f(u,c)$ for all $u \in \text{pred}(v)$ and all integers $c$ satisfying $0 \le c \le d$.  Call this "formula (*)".

Since the graph is guaranteed to be a dag, you can linearize it (topologically sort it).  Then, visit the vertices in topologically sorted order.  When you visit $v$, compute $f(v,d)$ for each possible $d$ using formula (*) -- this is possible because the topological sort ensures you will have computed $f(u,c)$ before visiting $v$.

There are $|V|$ possible vertices and at most $|V|$ possible values for the detail.  Calculating $f(v,d)$ can be done in $O(|V|)$ time, since the set $\text{pred}(v)$ has size at most $|V|$.  Therefore, the running time of this will be at most $O(|V|^3)$.

In practice, I expect the algorithm will be faster than that.  For instance, you only need to compute $f(v,d)$ for $d=0,1,2,\dots,\ell$, where $\ell$ is the length of the shortest path from $A$ to $v$.  Also, for most vertices, the size of $\text{pred}(v)$ will usually be much less than $|V|$ -- maybe more like $O(1)$.

Once you have computed $f(Z,0),f(Z,1),f(Z,2),\dots$, where $Z$ is the final node, then you can use all of that information to select which path you want.  For instance, if your criterion is "minimize erraticism, and break ties in favor of greater detail", you just compute $\min \{f(Z,d) : d=0,1,2,\dots\}$, resolving ties in favor of the larger $d$.  As another example, if you want to modify that criterion by ignoring all paths with detail 0, just ignore $f(Z,0)$.  Or, if you want to ignore all paths with detail 0 if there exists any path with detail $> 0$, then check whether any of $f(Z,1),f(Z,2),\dots$ are finite ($< +\infty$); if yes, then you ignore $f(Z,0)$.  And so on.  Hopefully you can see how to adapt the dynamic programming solution to handle many possible variations for the objective function.

For specific objective functions, there might well be even more efficient solutions -- but since it is not clear from your question at the time of writing just what objective function you want to minimize, I thought I would outline a general answer that works for a large class of possible objective functions.